# how to override Formik's handleBlur?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How do i overwrite or extend handleBlur? looking at the useFormik function, this is the implementation of handleBlur. Can someone tell me how to use this method? this is the first time me seeing a property that contains 2 functions. I'll appreciate if you can share a snippet. TIA!

```
handleBlur: {
        (e: React.FocusEvent<any>): void;
        <T = any>(fieldOrEvent: T): T extends string ? (e: any) => void : void;
};
```

This is the documentation,

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handleblur-e-any--void